# Hot reload rerenders all page if component is composed with HOC's

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hot-loader

I am trying to setup hot module replacement on `typscript` / `react` / `react-router v4` / `redux` project. I am trying to use `react-hot-loader` to persist react components state. It works with simple components, but it stops working (rerenders all app instead of the changed place) when I use HOC on the component, for ex. `withRouter` HOC:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactRouter from 'react-router';

export default ReactRouter.withRouter(class Test extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {
    render() {
        return <div>:)</div>
    }
});
```

I found a solution in [this](https://codeburst.io/how-to-hot-load-react-component-in-7-days-part-2-react-28ce2b61d0c7) article, that it is working, when you don't compose hoc's.

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactRouter from 'react-router';

class Test extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {
    render() {
        return <div>:)</div>
    }
}

export default ReactRouter.withRouter(Test);
```

This is very simplified example, but that is a bad solution, because there are a lot places in where I do have composed HOC's, like `connect` HOC to connect component to redux store and other. It feels wrong, because you have to silently know, that you can't do that, and somebody else might not know that.

My question is: is there a proper solution to be able to use `react-hot-loader` and hoc's?